# How to Build .net code packages to deploy on Windows 2012 R2 server?

Tags: visual-studio

We are using Visual Studio 2008 with .Net Frame Work 3.5 and build MSIs to deploy on Windows Server 2003  R2. Now we are looking to migrate to Windows Server 2012 R2, here my question how to build packages to make it compatible to WS 2012R2. And our current build server is Windows 2003 R2 32Bit. We are not ready to upgrade Visual Studio or .net Frame Work, so how we can achieve our goal? Do we need to upgrade our build server?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
MS

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to take advantage of new features of .NET, MSI, or Windows or you want 64-bit deployables you should be fine.

For instance, if you want to use features of .NET 4.5, you'll have to upgrade the OS because that version of .NET won't install on WS2003.

Comment: I don't want upgrade Visual Studio or .Net; with the same current setup (Visual Studio 2008 & >net 3.5) on which OS I have to build to deploy on Win 2012 R2. I mean what should be my build server setup? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like I said, Unless you *need* those other things, you should be ok  with your Windows Server 2003 system.  That OS is going end-of-life  in July 2015 2015, so you probably want to think about at least moving OS, but the toolset will still run.